# floating action button is not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

The problem I'm having is that when am click on button it should be come to top and floated. come to top is working but it not floated..can anyone suggest me for this problem......

code like bellow

```
<div class="create-course-info" id="scroll">
<a href="#" ><span class="count"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>                                      
</a>
</div>
```

css like bellow

```
.create-course-info {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.create-course-info .count {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: right;
    border: 3px solid #37abf2;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #666;
}
.fa-angle-up:before {
    content: "\f106";
}
```

script code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(window).scroll(function(){ 
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
                $('#scroll').fadeIn(); 
            } else { 
                $('#scroll').fadeOut(); 
            } 
        }); 
        $('#scroll').click(function(){ 
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600); 
            return false; 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set position of `create-course-info` to  `fixed`.

```
.create-course-info {
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r91eLchv/)

Comment: position:fixed; property is not working when am applying this property it displays none

Comment: @soumyapatel check the fiddle

Comment: ya m checking and m set these code in my file but it not displayed anything....is there any problem with another css is there any chance to effect another css like before section css ....??

Comment: if my code solves your problem please accept and upvote it

Answer (score 0):

No sure what you want to do with the float, but here is an JSFIDDLE example with your code and `Position` set to `Fixed` and an initial state of `Display:none`

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fqk0tedh/1/)

Comment: thanks for example..but it is not working in my code anyway thanku

Comment: if you scroll down on the HTML field to the right in the JSFIDDLE? @soumyapatel

Comment: @soumyapatel the fiddle is updated with text, try to scroll the text

Comment: @soumyapatel so you want the button to Always be displayed? Or do you want it to be hidden from the start and then be displayed after scroll?

Comment: I want it to be hidden from the start and then be displayed after scroll

Comment: so @soumyapatel please check this link out, this is your code with the fixes that i think you are looking fore https://jsfiddle.net/fqk0tedh/1/